# python sendemail script expecting authenication

Tags: python-3.x

I trying send email via python script with my company email id or donotreply@company.com.
Scripting throwing error you must authenticate.

python3 sendemail.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sendemail.py", line 99, in <module>
sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, subject, cc_addr_list, message, 
smtpserver="mail.company.net")
File "sendemail.py", line 73, in sendemail
problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (503, b'you must authenticate first 
(#5.5.1)', 'user@company.com')
```

Please suggest what exactly issue happening same step in jenkins test email works.